# Why jQuery.ready has strikethrough?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-code

When I copy and paste my code into this question, the `ready` does not have strike-through, but in my IDE (VS), you'll see that it looks like <strike>`ready`</strike>.

Does this mean anything? The code still seems to work, but if it's an issue, I'd like to figure it out now; as I want to use jQuery in the right way.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('.pets').hide();
    }
)
```

What I see in my VS:

[image: What I see on my VS]

Comment: if you hover over it, does it show the reason?

Comment: See this -https://api.jquery.com/ready/ ,its been deprecated

Comment: Visual studio is adding "intelli"sense to your code - hence the different colours and warnings.  Pasting into an SO snippet uses different rules to colour your code, and doesn't have deprecation checks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) says:

> jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the
> DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $( handler )
> $( document ).ready( handler )
> $( "document" ).ready( handler )
> $( "img" ).ready( handler )
> $().ready( handler )
> ```
>
> As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other
> syntaxes still work but are deprecated.

So change your code to:

```
$(function () {
    $('.pets').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Can you show me how to re-write my code with up to date syntax?

Comment: Nevermind, I see the link you shared. It shows me

$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});